# Datefield won't render completely - extjs4.2.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, render, extjs4.2, datefield

I have a afterrender event which should be called on my datefield in my formpanel.
however, it looks like it won't render, and so the afterrender event doesn't work.
any ideas why?

here's my code:

```
    this.activityFormPanelEdit = Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
        xtype: 'form',
        autoRender: true,
        layout: {
            align: 'stretch',
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        header: false,
        pollForChanges: false,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            layout: {
                align: 'stretch',
                type: 'hbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    name: 'reminderDate',
                    itemId: 'reminderDate',
                    fieldLabel: 'Erinnerung am',
                    padding: '10',
                    style: 'background-color: red',
                    disabled: true,
                    listener: {
                        afterrender: function (c) {
                            c.inputEl.on('dblclick', function () {
                                c.setValue(new Date());
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }]
        }]
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo in the code, per tritrotrash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

Name of config property where you can define event handlers is `listeners` not `listener`

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-listeners

Comment: ahhhhhh omg Sorry for that!!! thanks a lot again :)